# Children of the route of the current module return "Undefined"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to get all the routes of the current module which are lazy loaded. However whatever I've tried I never got the children out of it. The routes are available in `_loadedConfig.routes` but I can't access that.

This is my setup:

app-routing-module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'button', loadChildren: './pages/button/button.module#ButtonModule'},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'action-sheet', pathMatch: 'full'}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Component in which I want to get all lazy loaded routes:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ChildActivationEnd } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "button-component",
  templateUrl: "./button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./button.component.scss"]
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.config); // I want to get the lazy loaded routes here
  }
}
```

Module of that component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';
import { ChildPageComponent } from './child-page/child-page.component'


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ButtonComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'child-page',
        loadChildren: './child-page/child-page.module#ChildPageModule',
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ButtonComponent,
    ChildPageComponent,
  ]
})
export class ButtonModule {}
```

I just want to be able to get the route of `child-page`.

Stackblitz example (on path /button):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-i17ztz

Comment: Your route https://ionic-v4-i17ztz.stackblitz.io/button/child-page works as you declared it

Comment: That's not the question. The question is, how do I retrieve the `child-page` route. For example in a `console.log(child-page: Route)`

Comment: Not sure you can do that. But tell me what you want to do with it? Maybe I can help then. You can easy use it in a RouterLink or call navigate in a method

Comment: I want to retrieve all routes of that module as menu items and loop through them. That way I can make them dynamic instead of hard coding them. I add "data" to those routes to define the icons, title, etc..

Comment: In my experience I have not had that problem. Routes that loads a module is quite static. Either you have a couple of routes in ChildPageModule so adding them direct will probably not give you any headache. If you would have like 20 routes in the 'CPM' you might consider to create a route with url parameters. ex: something/[id]/something and do a loop in main model with routerLink to build it up. And consider lazy ButtonModule which contains  ChildPageModule. Feels like only Buttonmodules links should be shown first and when that module is loaded the CPM links should show up within it?

Comment: Ofcourse this is just a simulation of my problem which exists in my larger project. I have multiple lists in my actual project and I want to be able to manage those lists wthin the route configuration.